# Using authentication key as headers how can we call get api after login in flutter?

Tags: android, api, http, flutter, fetch-api

not get auth_key in response. i tired all but can not get solution

```
@override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        this.getJsonData();
      }

      Future<http.Request> getJsonData() async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            Uri.encodeFull("http://xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx"),
            headers: {'Header': 'xxxxxxxx',
              "Accept": "application/json",
            });

        print(response.body);//every time response get this "flutter:  {"error":true,"message":"Sorry, Auth key is not defined"}"

        setState(() {
          var convertDatatoJson = json.decode(response.body);

          data = convertDatatoJson['course_list'];//why not get auth_key in response
        });
    enter code here


        //return "Success";
      }
```

this is secondscreen.dart. In main.dart Button's onPress method i want to login and show list in another screen with using get api. from my side i login successfully but list did not see

Comment: The key for the key value pair maybe incorrect. EDIT You've asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195294/how-to-call-http-get-api-using-headers

Comment: Nope, in Android API working good. so the key and value pair is not incorrect

Comment: Is the header really called `header`? That seems really unusual. What do you send in postman?

Comment: Header - 7tJBAO3xwIF3UhfIwMYryL2Cqo1dpQ 


yes it is header as authentication